# Remove Rectangles Covering Text from PDF files exported from PowerPoint

Tags: pdf, document, pypdf

I have a set of PDF files that were exported from PowerPoint. The presentations had white rectangles over part of the text that covered information until the presenter moved it away. However, the PDF files, still have those rectangles. **The text is still in the document though**, and tools that can dump the text of PDF documents can still see all of the text.

I would like to write a script to systematically identify and remove these white rectangles so I can have just the clean content. My goal isn't to just extract the text, but rather remove the remove the rectangles so I can get a clean viewing experience.

I have taken a look at `PyPDF2` and it's methods but can't seem to figure out a path forward. I have tried dumping the objects in a page but haven't found anything that seems to resemble the rectangles. Other tools haven't really helped me either.

I have created a very minimal sample PDF document from Powerpoint that has one rectangle that hides a word. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXYx0OqBkS_4QiBRr3tyWYTqJBVqQLeV/view?usp=sharing) if you'd like to explore yourselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the PDF to JSON with `cpdf -output-json -output-json-parse-content-streams in.pdf -o out.json`, then make changes, then round-trip it back to PDF with `cpdf -j out.json -o final.pdf`.

However, it will not be a simple task. There may be other rectangles on the page you wish to keep, for example parts of graphics. You may need to identify rectangles which are a path made from four lines, rather than a rectangle operator. The rectangles might be in XObjects, instead of directly on pages. You may need to keep track of the graphics state to find which rectangles are actually white. And so on, and so on.

If you are really lucky, PowerPoint will have marked these rectangles in some special way. It is in your favour that all your PDF files are created from the same piece of software. But you will have to show an example PDF file if you would like more investigation...

Comment: Took your advice and broke it down. It gives a lot of the same results as libs like `PyPDF2`, although in a much nicer format. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that clearly resembles the boxes, even in a sample PDF that I made. There's also a lot of binary data that's included in the file.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to supply an example file?

Comment: I added a sample document to my question that you can take a look at if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the following JSON content should be deleted:

```
         [ "/P", { "/MCID": { "I": 2 } }, "BDC" ],
          [ { "F": 1.0 }, "g" ],
          [
            { "F": 517.08 },
            { "F": 270.0 },
            { "F": 114.72 },
            { "F": 67.08 },
            "re"
          ],
          [ "f*" ],
          [ { "F": 1.0 }, "w" ],
          [
            { "F": 0.184 }, { "F": 0.322 }, { "F": 0.5610000000000001 }, "RG"
          ],
          [
            { "F": 517.08 },
            { "F": 270.0 },
            { "F": 114.72 },
            { "F": 67.08 },
            "re"
          ],
          [ "S" ],
          [ "EMC" ]
```

We are deleting the whole marked content section between the BDC and EMC operators. But it is quite hard to detect. Perhaps the blue outline colour `{ "F": 0.184 }, { "F": 0.322 }, { "F": 0.5610000000000001 }, "RG"` is your best indicator?